# How to enable the declaration of clock_gettime() in <time.h> in CYGWIN when compiling for -std=c90?

Tags: c, time, cygwin, posix

In `<time.h>` in my CYGWIN installation `clock_gettime()` is defined under the check `#if defined(_POSIX_TIMERS)`. Now **_POSIX_TIMERS** is defined in my `<sys/features.h>` file only under the conditions -

1. If `__rtems__` is defined, or
2. If the following condition is met -
   `#if !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__) || defined(__cplusplus) || __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L`

Clearly condition 2 can not be met in my case.

Is there a (good) way I can set `__rtems__` or any other way I can make sure that **_POSIX_TIMERS** is enabled in my case (i.e. -std=c90 -pedantic)?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using the ancient C90 standard instead of C99 or C11? Newer standards would fulfill the second condition through `__STDC_VERSION__`.

Comment: To maximize portability.

Comment: Unless you have a specific legacy platform that requires C90, I would argue that not using C99 is counterproductive from portability point of view. C99 is a considerably improved standard compared to C90 and has some simple yet important features that improve portability, such as fixed width integer types that are very usefull for anyone dealing with communication protocols or embedded systems. Clearly Cygwin wants you to use C99, so working around it will likely bite you. `__ANYTHING__` is reserved for the C implementation, poking those approaches UB territory.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the C90 declaration as clock_gettime was defined after.

Anything else will be a trick prone to failure.

Comment: That still can bite you. Never to mess with system headers! OP should use standard C, if that is not possible, C99.

Comment: @Olaf I was referring to the gcc invocation. Not suggesting to touch the system header files

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. 1) Headers shall not include definitions (except for `inline` functions) 2) Any modification requires to modify the header. 3) changing standard macros (which are `#define`d, not declared) is strictly prohibited by the standard.

Comment: @Olaf To not use "-std=c90" in gcc invocation.

Comment: That is neither a declaration, nor a definition, but a compiler-option which tells the compiler to use a specific version of the standard. As gcc defaults to different versions of the C standard in different gc versions (4.x used C90, since 5.x it is C11), it is a good idea to tell it. So if you want to say "compile as C11 or C99", why don't you just write that? (and OP clearly states asks how to still compile as C90).

Comment: It is a definition as instruct the compiler to activate several internal `#define`.  Specifically between other things it adds `#define __STRICT_ANSI__ 1`

Comment: No! It tells the compiler which version of the standard to use! The definition of specific macros are just a side-effect as they are required by the standard. Howewer, it does not do any `#define XYZ` preprocessor macros; those macros are provided by the compiler, not some source code i.e. header (how would the headers know what to define? - chicken&egg problem).